# Unable to open a Webpage from IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have inserted some Url in a Javadoc comments in the IntelliJ Idea like this

```
 /**
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/10173996/932307</a>
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118564/932307"</a>
 */
```

and I downloaded the Hyperlink plugin. The idea is to open the webpage in default browser when Ctrl+click on the link.

When I press Ctrl and hover the mouse over the url the mouse pointer changes but when I click on the link a message comes **"cannot find deceleration to go to"** and url is not opened in the default browser.

How can I make this work?

**[Edit1]**

I changed the tag to

```
/**
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/10173996/932307">http://stackoverflow.com/q/10173996/932307</a>
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118564/932307">http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118564/932307</a>
 */
```

on clicking it still gives **"cannot find deceleration to go to"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperlink plug-in may be not compatible with the latest IDEA version, contact the plug-in vendor for help.

Please note that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it out of the box yet, vote for the following feature request:

- [IDEA-64131](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64131) support for links in comments

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your opening a tags are missing the '>' at the end, and that there is not text to display between start and end tag.

Having corrected that, the links work fine in the generated html. In intelliJ itself they don't seem to work. Yet it does work for references to Objects and methods.

here :

```
/**
 * <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/10173996/932307">http://stackoverflow.com/q/10173996/932307</a>
 * @see java.lang.String#compareTo(Object) 
 */
```

ctrl click works fine for clicking the packages, class or method. The stackoverflow link does not work from source code though.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer as close as possible but I can only choose one answer and @crazycoder is much closer.