# How to check if the call is missed or answered with CallLog

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I have a content observer for call log change

```
class CallContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    Context context;

    public CallContentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver()
                              .query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null, null, "Calls._ID DESC");

       mCursor.moveToFirst();

        //How do I know the call is answered or missed ?
```

As show above, in the `onChange()` callback, I would like to get the latest call log which caused this `onChange()` be triggered.

**I have 2 questions:**

**1.** After I got the latest call log item, how do I know whether the call is answered or missed ?

**2.** It seems the onChange() get called twice when I start a call, but I only want to access CallLog once when call start, how to get rid of this 2 times triggered problem of `onChange()` ?

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
Integer type=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
switch(type){
    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
       /// do something
       break;
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
       /// do something
       break;
    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
       /// do something
       break;
}
```

2. try to set second argument in registerContentObservable() to false, look at p.3 there:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10767455/2751697

Comment: Hi, thanks, however your answer to my 1st question is not what I need. I know that, and tried that, but what I mean is to find a way to be aware of whether the outgoing call is answered or not. In your answer, the MISSED_TYPE means the incoming call is missed, whereas INCOMING_CALL means the incoming call has answered, but what about outgoing call's state of answered or not?

Comment: seems, there are no way to do this, because we have no event no states to signal about answering.